# Triangle drawing with OpenGL: how to manage with two classes

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I have a problem with this code. No errors or warnings, but triangle appears when window is resizing only.

I need to correct this. Header file contain this two classes: Window and WindowGL (class-based inheritance). What's wrong with this code?

```
#ifndef OPENGL_H
#define OPENGL_H
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

class Window
{
protected:
    HWND hwnd;
    long clientWidh;
    long clientHeight;
public:
    Window() :hwnd(NULL){};
    LRESULT WndProc(HWND , UINT , WPARAM , LPARAM );
    bool Initialize(HINSTANCE appHandle, POINT windowPosition, POINT windowSize);
    WPARAM Run();
};

class WindowGL : public Window
{
private:
    HGLRC handleRC;
    HDC handleDC;
    bool InitWGL(HWND hwnd);
    void DestroyWGL();
    void SetScene(bool isometricProjection);
    void Render();
public:
    WindowGL() :Window(), handleRC(NULL), handleDC(NULL){};
    LRESULT WndProc(HWND, UINT , WPARAM, LPARAM );
    bool SetPixels(HDC) const;
}window;

#endif
```

And .cpp file:

```
#include "myHeaderGL.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>// not used in this example

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return window.WndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    POINT windowPosition = { 100, 100 };
    POINT windowSize = { 800, 600 };
    if (!window.Initialize(hInstance, windowPosition, windowSize))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Initialisation fail.", "OpenGL Application", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else return window.Run();

}

LRESULT Window::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        clientWidh = rect.right - rect.left;
        clientHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        break;
    default:
        return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));
    }
    return 0L;
}

LRESULT WindowGL::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    long result = Window::WndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); 
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        if (!InitWGL(hWnd))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Render context fail to load", "My OpenGL", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        SetScene(false);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DestroyWGL();
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        SetScene(false);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        Render();
        ValidateRect(hWnd, NULL);
        break;
    //default: 
        //return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));
    }
    return result;
}

bool Window::Initialize(HINSTANCE appHandle, POINT windowPosition, POINT windowSize)
{
    char windowName[] = "My 1 OpenGL";

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC; 
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)::WndProc; 
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0; 
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0; 
    wc.hInstance = appHandle; 
    wc.hIcon = NULL; 
    wc.hIconSm = NULL; 
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL; 
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = windowName; 

    if (RegisterClassEx(&wc) == 0) return false;

    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        windowName,
        windowName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        windowPosition.x, windowPosition.y,
        windowSize.x, windowSize.y,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        appHandle,
        NULL
        );
    if (!hwnd) return false;

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    return true;
}

WPARAM Window::Run()
{
    MSG msg = {0};
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        window.Render();
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

bool WindowGL::SetPixels(HDC handleDC) const
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    int pixFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(handleDC, &pfd);
    if (pixFormat == 0) return false;
    if (!SetPixelFormat(handleDC, pixFormat, &pfd)) return false;

    return true;
}

bool WindowGL::InitWGL(HWND hwnd)
{
    handleDC= ::GetDC(hwnd);
    if (!SetPixels(handleDC)) return false;

    handleRC = wglCreateContext(handleDC);
    if (handleRC == NULL) return false;
    if (!wglMakeCurrent(handleDC, handleRC)) return false;
    return true;
}

void WindowGL::SetScene(bool isometricProjection)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, clientWidh, clientHeight);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float wsp = clientHeight / (float)clientWidh;
    if (!isometricProjection)
        glFrustum(-1.0f, 1.0f, wsp*-1.0f, wsp*1.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
    else
        glOrtho(-1.0f, 1.0f, wsp*-1.0f, wsp*1.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void WindowGL::DestroyWGL()
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(handleRC);
    ::ReleaseDC(hwnd, handleDC);
}

void WindowGL::Render()
{
    const float x0 = 1.0f;
    const float y0 = 1.0f;
    const float z0 = 1.0f;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(-x0, -y0,  0.0f); 
        glVertex3f( x0, -y0,  0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, y0,  0.0f);
    glEnd();

    SwapBuffers(handleDC); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Render()` only when `WM_PAINT` is sent, try to call it in `Run()` once every a few milliseconds.
Change GetMessage with PeekMessage to prevent the code from stalling, then use GetMessage only if there's a message to read.

**EDIT**

```
while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
         TranslateMessage(&msg);
         DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    Render();
    sleep(10); // If you don't want to update the screen too fast
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
LRESULT Window::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_SIZE || WM_PAINT: // <- the problem was here
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        clientWidh = rect.right - rect.left;
        clientHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        break;
    default:
        return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));
    }
    return 0L;
}
```

Comment: Sry for this. I have updated the Run() function. But still the same problem. No triangle without changing window size.

Comment: I edited the code, it should give you the right idea.

Comment: Yes, i edited my code above previously - and changed Run() with "better" function PeekMessage() but still no effect. Header classes are build that way, i can't even call Render() inside Run(). Instead i can call: window. Render() but it doesn't change anything. Code comes from a book written by a physicist but author doesn't provide a source code. Can You try compile this stuff on your machine? Thanks for Your help.

Comment: Extremely grateful to You FedeWar. I checked my book and what I have found? There is a mistake. I will send back it to shop probably. Thanks again, how can i reward you?

Comment: You are welcome, reward me choosing this answer as the best.

Comment: Your proposed message loop is wrong. It calls `Render` once **after** receiving (and handling) a `WM_QUIT` message. `sleep(10)` (assuming you are calling the POSIX implementation) sleeps for 10 **seconds**. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: First: sleeps for 10 milliseconds, second: I compiled it and it worked perfectly

Comment: That would be [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) then, with an uppercase `S`. The lowercase `sleep` is the POSIX implementation, that takes an argument as seconds. *"I compiled it and it worked perfectly"* - You cannot test for undefined behavior. It's something you have to know. I just pointed out, that you are rendering to a window, that has already gone. If it wasn't for the built-in error resilience of this particular OpenGL implementation, your application would go up in flames.

Comment: Yeah you are right I used sleep but here I wrote Sleep. I understand the problem, I wrote that code just to give an idea, I should have spent more time checking it.